# Python - Groupby Multiple Criteria and Closest Integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

Here, I am trying to assign groups based on multiple criteria and the closest date diff prior to the zero. The groupby should look only within each ID, then find the closest negative datediff value prior to each zero (not positive, I am trying to look back in time), and based on the Location integer, assign a group. I will have hundreds of groups, and the groups should be assigned based on the Location integer. So, multiple IDs can have the same groups if the Location is the same

Please let me know if I should elaborate or reword - thank you for your help!

Input:

```
ID  Location Date Diff (Days)
111 87       -5               
111 88        0
123 97       -123
123 98       -21              
123 55        0
123 56       -59
123 30       -29              
123 46        0
123 46        25
123 31        87
234 87       -32              
234 55        0
234 30       -26
234 54        0
```

Expected Output:

```
ID  Location Date Diff (Days) Group
111 87       -5               1
111 88        0
123 97       -123
123 98       -21              2
123 55        0
123 56       -59
123 30       -29              3
123 46        0
123 46        25
123 31        87
234 87       -32              1
234 55        0
234 30       -26              3
234 54        0
```

Comment: Thanks for the question. Since "87" was already assigned Group 1 earlier by ID 111, it should remain Group 1. Let me know if I should rephrase my question better, but the groupings should be based on the Location number.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand: does the _order_ rows as they appear in the `df` matter? From the way you phrased your question, it seems like it shouldn't matter. But observing your expected output example - it seems like it does. It seems like you assume e.g. that `Date Diff (Days)` is monotonically increasing between subsequent "runs" of the same ID.

(but if that's indeed the case, then there's a chance that your question is not well-defined, e.g. maybe "123, 56" and "123, 30" belong to different "runs"? (and therefore "123, 56" should also be associated with "Group"))

Comment: You are correct that "123, 56" and "123, 30" would belong to different runs, however, the only run I'd like to tag is the closest negative value to each zero. The order of the rows may not matter, but I think it does only because it groups IDs together and currently assigns the datediff.

Comment: So: does the order of rows matter, or not? Specifically, consider ID=234 and the last 4 rows: if the data was sorted by `Date Diff`, then that ID would be associated with just one group (3). But only because of that specific order in your example, that ID is associated with two groups (1 and 3).

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, the order of the rows matter.

Comment: ok, working on a suggested response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can find the index to add a group value by using `where` and mask all values in Diff (I renamed the column Date Diff (Days) by Diff for simplicity) greater or equal to 0. Then `groupby` ID and groups made of where the column Diff, once `shift` is equal to 0 and `cumsum`. For each group get the `idxmax`. Clean the nan and get the list of all indexes. Second step is to use this list of index and the column Location to create unique ID for each Location with `pd.factorize`

```
idx = (df['Diff'].where(lambda x: x.lt(0))
                 .groupby([df['ID'], 
                           df['Diff'].shift().eq(0).cumsum()])
                 .idxmax().dropna().tolist()
      )
df['Group'] = ''
df.loc[idx, 'Group'] = (pd.factorize(df.loc[idx, 'Location'])[0]+1)
print (df)
     ID  Location  Diff Group
0   111        87    -5     1
1   111        88     0      
2   123        97  -123      
3   123        98   -21     2
4   123        55     0      
5   123        56   -59      
6   123        30   -29     3
7   123        46     0      
8   123        46    25      
9   123        31    87      
10  234        87   -32     1
11  234        55     0      
12  234        30   -26     3
13  234        54     0
```

Comment: Ben, you never cease to amaze me - thanks! If I may, I do have some questions as I just want to better understand how to manipulate queries and write my own as I continue to take some courses. If I want to include the datediff of zero in the groups, all I need to do is remove the "+1" from the query, correct? There may be instances where the datediff is just zero throughout for a member because  the prior visits were on the same day as my "anchor point."

Comment: @Logan IIUC, you mean that let's say where currently Group 2 start, the value un Diff is -21, but could be 0 and you still want the group 2 start at this row because this 0 is not a Anchor point?

Comment: Note that there's a small bug in Ben's awesome code: the `.eq(0)` assumes the existence of such value (`0`) in each "run". (e.g. try to replace the "123,55,0" row with "123,55,1")

Comment: @Ben. T, Correct! Since both datediffs will be 0, by removing the "+1" in the code, would I then be able to assign both of the 0s a group value?

Comment: @Logan no the +1 you mean is not at all related to this, it was to get group number starting at one instead of 0 as pd.factorize start the mapping of unique value at 0 not 1 :) but for your question then it would be more simple to have access to the Anchor column, and I would do something in the where like: `where(df['Diff'].le(0)&df['Anchor'].ne('Y'))` to mask the value in diff strictly positive and the Anchor rows (would need some validation though)

Comment: @Yaniv it is not really a bug but more a misinterpretation of the question, when I red `closest negative datediff value prior to each zero`, in my mind it sounds like the negative value closest to 0 aka the maximum value under 0. But I see your interpretation, now, maybe the OP can confirm?

Comment: @Logan and then in the groupby, `df['Diff'].shift().eq(0).cumsum()` becomes `df['Anchor'].shift().eq('Y').cumsum()` as you don't now anymore that 0 in Diff is a new group. Also if you can clarify my previous comment to Yaniv with what they pointed out?

Comment: @Yaniv, thanks for the comment. In my case, each ID will always have at least one diff of 0.

Comment: @Ben. T Finally, how would I go about skipping certain Location values? For example, for ID 123, I want to skip Location 98 and jump to the next closest, Location 97. How can I go about creating exception rules like that?

Comment: @Logan I would say also in the `where`, you can add `where(df['Diff'].le(0)&df['Anchor'].ne('Y')&df['Location'].ne(98))` to remove this location form the logic after, but here it starts to be too far from the original question :)

Comment: @Ben.T Thanks for all of your help. I won't be a bother much longer, I'm just tying everything up, and thought I should create a new question for my new problem to be appropriate. Would you be able to look at the below please?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63142055/python-grouping-and-assigning-exception-rules

Answer (score 1):

Because the order of rows matter, the most straightforward answer that that I can think of (that will have a somewhat *readable code*) can use a *loop*... So I sure hope that performance is not an issue.

The code is less cumbersome than it seems. I hope that the code comments are clear enough.

```py
# Your data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[111,87,-5],
          [111,88,0],
          [123,97,-123],
          [123,98,-21],
          [123,55,0],
          [123,56,-59],
          [123,30,-29],
          [123,46,0],
          [123,46,25],
          [123,31,87],
          [234,87,-32],
          [234,55,0],
          [234,30,-26],
          [234,54,0]], columns=['ID','Location','Date Diff (Days)'])
N_ID, N_Location, N_Date, N_Group = 'ID', 'Location', 'Date Diff (Days)', 'Group'

# Some preparations
col_group = pd.Series(index=df.index)  # The final column we'll add to our `df`
groups_found = 0
location_to_group = dict()  # To maintain our mapping of Location to "group" values

# LOOP
prev_id, prev_DD, best_idx = None, None, None
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    #print(idx, row.values)
    
    if prev_id is None:
        if row[N_Date] < 0:
            best_idx = idx
            #best_date_diff_in_this_run = row[N_Date]
    else:
        if row[N_ID] != prev_id or row[N_Date] < prev_DD:
            # Associate a 'group' value to row with index `best_idx`
            if best_idx is not None:
                best_location = df.loc[best_idx, N_Location]
                if best_location in location_to_group:
                    col_group.loc[best_idx] = location_to_group[best_location]
                else:
                    groups_found += 1
                    location_to_group[best_location] = groups_found
                    col_group.loc[best_idx] = groups_found
            # New run
            best_idx = None
        
        # Regardless, update best_idx
        if row[N_Date] < 0:
            best_idx = idx
            #best_date_diff_in_this_run = row[N_Date]
        
    # Done
    prev_id, prev_DD = row[N_ID], row[N_Date]
    
# Deal with the last "run" (same code as the one inside the loop)
# Associate a 'group' value to row with index `best_idx`
if best_idx is not None:
    best_location = df.loc[best_idx, N_Location]
    if best_location in location_to_group:
        col_group.loc[best_idx] = location_to_group[best_location]
    else:
        groups_found += 1
        location_to_group[best_location] = groups_found
        col_group.loc[best_idx] = groups_found

# DONE
df['Group'] = col_group
```

Comment: Thank you, Yaniv! Your patience and code will help me become better at my work as I continue to take python courses!